# Stuck trying to hydrate ReactJS.net SSR components in raw HTML from Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, umbraco, reactjs.net

I have an Umbraco CMS loosely working with ReactJS.net. I've got a root `<App>` component which takes an array `prop` of (Umbraco Node ID and Path) objects, used to generated a `<Route>` for each page in the site using a `<Content>` comp. `<App>` is rendered in an `UmbracoViewPage` and renders fine in a client browser - with `@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()`, it gets hydrated as expected.

The `<Content>` component loads up the page HTML using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. I've got a few custom Umbraco grid editors which, instead of generating conventional markup in the ASP .NET view, instead call `@Html.React()` to render a custom React component which might take a `prop` or two.

On initial page load, the grid HTML is generated server-side and these nested components work fine in the browser, because ReactJS.net is passing `ReactDOM.hydrate()` calls for each grid component (triggered by `@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()`).

BUT as soon as there is a frontend route change, the `<App>` mounts the relevant `<Content>` comp based on the path and this calls an Umbraco `SurfaceController` with the Umbraco Node ID. The page grid HTML for that node is returned and loaded as before using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

The problem is I now have raw HTML which includes multiple React components which need hydrating. Because it's loading in the browser, there is no longer a `@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()` call hydrating all the components individually.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Answering my own question in case it helps anyone who is playing with Umbraco and React and is aiming for a tighter integration.

**TL;DR** - Include a list of component names, React IDs and props in my content API responses, allowing my frontend code to handle it much the same as ReactJS.NET's [`@Html.ReactInitJavaScript`](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/blob/e5cb5d86c541746565cc6fa9a0a5d162ef052ec4/src/React.AspNet/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs#L154) helper does (I think).

My solution was to modify my [`SurfaceController`](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/surface-controllers) to include a list all of the React components rendered in the markup. So it does much the same as ReactJS.NET's [`@Html.ReactInitJavaScript`](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/blob/e5cb5d86c541746565cc6fa9a0a5d162ef052ec4/src/React.AspNet/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs#L154) helper but in my `SurfaceController` API method.

I extended ReactJS.NET's [`@Html.React`](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/blob/e5cb5d86c541746565cc6fa9a0a5d162ef052ec4/src/React.AspNet/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs#L61) helper so that details about the component called are also added to a custom helper service I named `ReactComponentHydrator` ([gist](https://gist.github.com/charlieanstey/64ec831882727f0e0f0a02f9d97350e8), per-request singleton)*. For each component, I store the component name (e.g. `Component.ExampleComponent`), the React ID included in the HTML markup (e.g. `react_d1gC4eKqaUatZWfAdtjkTA`) and the props sent with it.

From that, in the frontend code I am to create and [hydrate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate) each component once the HTML has been loaded via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

*ReactJS.NET [does seem to keep track of each component called](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/blob/e5cb5d86c541746565cc6fa9a0a5d162ef052ec4/src/React.Core/ReactEnvironment.cs#L76) but this is internal and not exposed through any API I could find.